# How to create a view from multiple tables?

Tags: oracle, sql-view

```
CREATE VIEW Te AS
SELECT
select sno,sname,dept,'madinah'as universty name from med_std
union
select sno,sname,dept,'yanbu'as universty name from yun_std
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you have and why MySQL _and_ SQL Server?

Comment: ERROR at line 3:
ORA-00936: missing expression

Comment: So, nothing do do with MySQL _or_ SQL Server at all then but Oracle...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two SELECT statements in a row; remove one of them:

```
CREATE VIEW Te AS
select sno, sname, dept, 'madinah' as universty name from med_std
union
select sno, sname, dept, 'yanbu' as universty name from yun_std
```

Whilst you're at it you may want to seriously consider normalising your database; why does every university have a separate table? If you put it all in one table then you don't need to query multiple tables.

Furthermore, I'd highly recommend using UNION ALL in this situation if at all possible, instead of UNION. UNION  will attempt to do a distinct sort on the result set; as your university's have different names between the two tables there is no need to do a distinct so you might just as well not attempt it. You should only use UNION if you want to remove duplicates from within *one* of your tables. See [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/queries004.htm#SQLRF52341) for more information.